# Sum of three squares of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z,u,v,w]$ with $6$ variables, I would like to know if
there exist $f,g,h\in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z,u,v,w]$ such that 
$$
(x^2+y^2+z^2)(u^2+v^2+w^2)=f^2+g^2+h^2.
$$
Any reference/proof about this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/hurwitzlinear.pdf

Comment: Great! Wonderful link! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please turn that comment into an answer.